# Evaluate the distances between two points situated on the plane using Python

Tags: python

This is how we imagine the class:

1. it's called Point;
2. its constructor accepts two arguments (x and y respectively), both default to zero;
   all the properties should be private;
3. the class contains two parameterless methods called getx() and gety(), which return each of the 
   two coordinates (the coordinates are stored privately, so they cannot be accessed directly 
   from within the object);
4. the class provides a method called distance_from_xy(x,y), which calculates and returns the 
   distance between the point stored inside the object and the other point given as a pair of floats;
5. the class provides a method called distance_from_point(point), which calculates the distance
    (like the previous method), but the other point's location is given as another Point class object;

I am not able to understand what code to be written for point number 5, so far what I have got is:

```
import math

class Point:
    def __init__(self, x=0.0, y=0.0):
        self.__x = x
        self.__y = y

    def getx(self):
        return self.__x

    def gety(self):
        return self.__y

    def distance_from_xy(self, x, y):
        return math.hypot(self.__x - x, self.__y - y)

    def distance_from_point(self, point):
        """ This part is the question"""

"""Output to be based on below objects """
point1 = Point(0, 0)
point2 = Point(1, 1)
print(point1.distance_from_point(point2))
print(point2.distance_from_xy(7, 3))
```

Comment: It's as simple as `return self.distance_from_xy(self, point.x, point.y)`.

Comment: #5 is exactly the same as #4, but you're given another object of the `Point` class instead of the `x` and `y` coordinates like in #4. All  you need to do is call the other function and specify that you want to use the `x` and `y` values that are already specified in the _given `point`_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#5 is exactly the same as #4, but you're given another object of the Point class instead of the x and y coordinates like in #4. All you need to do is call the other function and specify that you want to use the x and y values that are already specified in the given point (thanks to **@PranavHosangadi** for the comment)

```
import math

class Point:
    def __init__(self, x=0.0, y=0.0):
        self.__x = x
        self.__y = y

    def getx(self):
        return self.__x

    def gety(self):
        return self.__y

    def distance_from_xy(self, x, y):
        return math.hypot(self.__x - x, self.__y - y)

    def distance_from_point(self, point):
        return self.distance_from_xy(point.__x, point.__y)
```

Alternatively you might also try this:

```
def distance_from_point(self, point):
    return math.hypot(self.__x - point.__x, self.__y - point.__y)
```

You can use either `point.__x` or `point.getx()`.